# How to send a message to multiple jms endpoints, since the <all> router is deprecated

Tags: mule, integration

I'd like to send a map payload to multiple jms recipients using a recipient-list router similar to Spring Integration's recipient-list router. Mule provides an ALL router but that has been deprecated. I don't want to use scatter-gather since it is unable to do what I want. The question would obviously arise ,why not use a topic. The answer is that I am dealing with legacy infrastructure. I need to be able to send to all the queues. Also, failing to send to one of the queues in the list should prevent the message being sent to the others. How can I simulate a recipient list in Mule? Here's an idea of what I'd like to achieve:

```
<flow name="product.queue">
 <processor-chain>
   <transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN">
    <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="xa-mail.queue" queue="mail">
    <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="xa-reports.queue" queue="reports">
    <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="xa-recltn.queue" queue="recltn">
  </transaction>
 </processor-chain>
 </flow>
```

The message is sent to every queue in the list but it should fail and roll back transactionally if it fails to deliver the message to any in the list.

Comment: Why does the scatter gather not work for you? It can be configured to work like the all component if you add a ```<threading-profile doThreading="false"/>```.

Comment: The endpoints are completely unrelated and process the messages in their own way.  ** Second the documentation states: Like the All router, this configuration ensures that the routes are invoked sequentially. However, there is one difference: unlike with the All router, with this configuration if one route fails the subsequent routes are still invoked.**, which as I stated is undesirable. It's an all or nothing deal

Comment: To be honest, the ALL router doesn't do what I want anyway. It's seems like Mule doesn't have a true recipient-list router which can send copies to each recipient

Comment: Have you looked into Multiple Resource Transactions?

Comment: All the queues use the same connection factory so they are not really multi resource transactions are they?